# Как упростить два обработчика события?

Tags: javascript, jquery, инспекция-кода

Мой код работает. Но думаю, что как-то не так написал. Можно ли такое сократить?

```js
$( "#clickbtn_recovery" ).click(function() {
  $( ".modal-backdrop.in" ).hide( 500 );
});
  $( "#clickbtn_recovery" ).click(function() {
  $( "#exampleModal_auth" ).hide( 500 );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="clickbtn_recovery">кнопка нажать</div>
<div class="modal-backdrop.in" id="exampleModal_auth">Тут прячутся два разных элемента</div>
```

HTML-код модального окна под спойлером ниже.

```html
 <!-- HTML-код модального окна -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal_auth" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Авторизация</h4>
      </div>
 <!-- Основное содержимое модального окна -->
      <div class="modal-body"> 
               <form role="form" class="formForMe" id="register_form" method="post">
               <div class="input-group">
               <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="add-on"><i class="fa fa-at" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></span>
               <input type="text" class="input form-control" id="email_auth" placeholder="Ваша почта" required autofocus />
               </div>   
               <div class="input-group">
               <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="add-on"><i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></span>
               <input type="text" class="input form-control" id="password_auth" placeholder="Ваш будующий пароль" required autofocus />
               </div>
                     <p class="bg-danger_auth" id="bg-danger_auth">...</p>   
                     <p class="success_auth" id="success_auth">...</p>   
                     <p class="error" id="error">...</p>                 
      </div>
      <!-- Футер модального окна -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" value="1" class="clickButtonForm btn btn-block btn-info" id="clickButtonForm_auth">Зарегистрироваться</button>
        <button type="button" value="1" class="clickButtonForm btn btn-block btn-info" id="clickbtn_recovery" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal_recovery">Востановить пароль</button>
        </form>     
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>         
 <!-- HTML-код модального окна -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal_recovery" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Востановление</h4>
      </div>
 <!-- Основное содержимое модального окна -->
      <div class="modal-body"> 
               <form role="form" action="client-reg/ajax_recovery.php" class="formForMe" id="register_form" method="post">
               <div class="input-group">
               <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="add-on"><i class="fa fa-at" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></span>
               <input type="text" class="input form-control" name="email_recovery" id="email_recovery" placeholder="Ваша почта" required autofocus />
               </div>   
                     <p class="bg-danger_auth" id="bg-danger_auth">...</p>   
                     <p class="success_auth" id="success_auth">...</p>   
                     <p class="error" id="error">...</p>                 
      </div>
      <!-- Футер модального окна -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="clickButtonForm btn btn-block btn-info" id="clickButtonForm_for_recovery">Востановить</button>
        </form>     
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Хочу посоветовать, вылаживайте не весь код, а только ту чать, которую затрагивает скрипт

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Селекторы можно перечислять через запятую:

```
$( "#clickbtn_recovery" ).click(function() {
  $( ".modal-backdrop.in, #exampleModal_auth" ).hide( 500 );
});
```

Comment: спасибо, я почти так пробовал ".modal-backdrop.in", "#exampleModal_auth" и из - за ковычек не срабатовало